# Web worker type import broken after upgrading to Typescript 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack-5

I need some help how to import web worker type. it used to work in typescript 4.8 but after upgrading to typescript 5, it started giving me compilation error.

Here is my details .. I have a typescript file called "XhrWorker.vbworker.ts"

```
const ctx: Worker = self as any;
 let xhrLoader;
 ctx.addEventListener('message', onMessage);
function onMessage({ data }) {
   //some code here
}
```

I created a custom.d.ts file in the same folder with below code

```
declare module "*.vbworker.ts" {
   class WebpackWorker extends Worker {
    constructor();
   }
   export default WebpackWorker; }
```

and now I have another ts file XhrWorkerLoader.ts where I am importing it

```
import XhrWorker from './XhrWorker.vbworker.ts';
export class XhrWorkerLoader {
 private worker: XhrWorker;
 constructor() {
    this.worker = new XhrWorker()
 }
}
```

After upgrading to typescript 5, I got two errors.

1. Module "/XhrWorker.vbworker"' has no default export for the line
2. An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled.

I fixed the 2nd error by adding "allowImportingTsExtensions": true in my tsconfig.
but I am not able to solve the first error.

I am using webpack5 for my bundling. I have worker-loader in my webpack5 config.

Any help would highly be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try adding a default export for `ctx` in `XhrWorker.vbworker.ts`.